# when I run my code it executes 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0?

Tags: java

```
  import java.util.*;

  /*  For example, 371 is an Armstrong number since 3**3 + 7**3 + 1**3 = 371. 
   * Write a program to find all Armstrong number in the range of 0 and 999.
   */


  public class Armstrong {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int no=1,rem=1,mod=1,armstrong;
        //check for armstrong
        System.out.println("Enter armstrong no to be checked: ");
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        no=sc.nextInt();
        armstrong=no;
                while(no>=0)
                {
                    System.out.println(no);
                mod=no%10;
                System.out.println(no);
                rem=rem+(mod*mod*mod);
                System.out.println(no);
                no=no/10;
                System.out.println(no);
                }
                if(no==armstrong)
                    System.out.println("it is armstrong no");

      }

   }
```

Comment: 0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
this is the output

Comment: Please dont flag it duplicate as I know armstrong no code I want to know where I went wrong with my code. Thanks.

Comment: What's your input?

Comment: I'm guessing http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4685450/why-is-the-result-of-1-3-0

Comment: `while(no>=0)` will loop until `no` is negative. When do you expect that to happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Avoid infinite loop. Change

   ```
   while(no>=0)
   ```

   to

   ```
   while(no>0)
   ```

   Since `no=no/10;` can reduce a positive number least to `0`. Not less than that.

---

2. Assign `rem=0` since this is where you are calculating the sum.

Comment: thanks atleast its not going into infinite loop but still it is

Comment: @Shashank cool, if that solves the problem, be kind enough to mark it as an answer.

Comment: how do i do that?